# Countif, range, and cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in VBA that is returning an 1004 error:

```
e = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("TG Teams").Range(Cells(4, w), Cells(12, w)), Worksheets("Calcs").Range("B" & a))
```

e, w, and a are all integers.

The code is meant to check if a name in the Calcs sheet also appears in a TG Teams sheet. The reason that the range is variable is that the CountIf needs to check a different column each week.

Any ideas how to resolve the error 1004 I get when I run this?

Comment: You need to assign the parent to **ALL** the range objects : `Worksheets("TG Teams").Range(Worksheets("TG Teams").Cells(4, w), Worksheets("TG Teams").Cells(12, w))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fully qualify `(Cells(4, w), Cells(12, w))` as well with the worksheet ("TG Teams") they are in, use `With`:

```
With Worksheets("TG Teams")
    e = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(4, w), .Cells(12, w)), Worksheets("Calcs").Range("B" & a))
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I'll accept it in a few minutes

Comment: Why do I feel like "you need to fully qualify `Cells` calls" is the answer to 80% of VBA runtime error questions?